# When I create an account from command line, I cannot login to the account using the login command

Tags: accounts, macos

I want to create some accounts on a macOS system that don't have a home directory or an icon on the login page

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser UserShell /bin/bash
```

The issue is when I type:

```
login hiddenuser
```

It just says `login incorrect`, and then just says `login:` that I cannot <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> out of. It does not even let me type the password, even if I set it. How can I create a hidden user not shown in the login page, but that I can log in to using the terminal? However, if I create a user via System Preferences, it can be logged in by `login`, but it is not hidden. How can I create a hidden user through the terminal that can be logged in to?

Comment: Are you basically wanting to create a user for a service on macOS (like the pre-existing `_postfix` and `_www` users)?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have to perform a few more steps than just creating the user and settings it's shell.

If, like you, I run the following commands:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hideuser
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hideuser UserShell /bin/bash
```

And then inspect the users on the system with `dscacheutil -q user`, I can not see the new `hideuser` user account and if I try to login I get `Login incorrect`.

You need to define the new users UID (User ID), by running the following command:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hideuser UniqueID 1002
```

The number after "UniqueID" (i.e 1002) must be an ID number that is not assigned to another user. You can find this by inspecting the output of and looking at the uid's assigned to users.

```
 dscacheutil -q user
```

You then need to assign the user a primary group:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/hideuser PrimaryGroupID 1001.
```

This PrimaryGroupID can be the same as the UID.

It is at this stage the user will show up when running

```
dscacheutil -q user
```

You can now set the password for the account:

```
sudo dscl . -passwd /Users/hideuser password
```

This user can now successfully be logged into:

```
Bens-iMac:~ macuser$ login hideuser
Password:
Bens-iMac:~ hideuser$ whoami
hideuser
```

At this point, the user can be logged into but unfortunately it will show up in the lists of users and login window, to hide this user you need to run the following command:

```
sudo dscl . create /Users/hideuser IsHidden 1
```

Unfortunately, this will make a 'Other' option displayed at the login prompt, to hide this (note: this will hide the Guest User if you have it enabled) you can run the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE
```